# Creating Inverse Probability of Attrition Weights in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, weighted, inverse

Weuve et al. (2012) wrote a great paper about implementing Inverse Probability of Attrition Weighting (IPAW), a weighting method used to account for bias introduced by attrition during the course of a longitudinal study. Here is a link to said article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3237815/#R30

I am working on a project where I am trying to implement this IPAW method and there isn't much out there on how to implement and code this method, so I'm looking for some help just to make sure I'm doing everything correctly.

The data I am working with involves older individuals who may have dementia, so it makes sense to use IPAW because those with dementia are more likely to leave the study. Each individual has at least a baseline visit and then up to 12 follow up visit (the average number of visits for each person is around 3). My understanding is that I should create weights for each round of follow up visits, so I start by subsetting the data to only a certain visit, creating a variable for whether or not somebody drops out immediately following the visit, and then I proceed to creating the models and weights.

Below is the r code I have been using to generate the weights:

## Creating weights for the first follow up visit (visit == 1)

#### for-loop to create a variable for attrition

```
(For ease, I am just calling the last observation "x")

data$attrition<-c()
data$attrition[x] <- 1
for (i in 1:x){
  if(data$visit[i+1] == 0) {
    data$attrition[i] = 1
  } else {
    data$attrition[i] = 0
  }
}
```

#### subsetting to only get the data for the first follow up visit

```
data_visit1 <-subset(data, data$visit == 1)
```

#### creating stepwise model for the likelihood of attriting

```
# specifying null model 
null_visit1 <- glm(attrition ~ 1, family = binomial, data = data_visit1)


# specifying full model  --
full_visit1 <- glm(attrition~
              predictor1 +
              predictor2 + 
              ...,
              family = binomial, data = data_visit1)



# running combined selection

stepmodel_visit1 <- step(null_visit1, scope=list(lower = null_visit1, upper = full_visit1), direction = "forward", k=2)
```

#### Creating weights

```
# re-naming model for denominator  
denom.model <- stepmodel_visit1

  
# creating the predicted categorizations
pd_visit1 <- predict(denom.model, type = "response") 


## estimation of numerator of ip weights using stabilizer instead of just 1

numer.model <- glm(attrition ~ 1, family = binomial(), data = data_visit1)


# predicting the numerator values

pn_visit1 <- predict(numer.model, type = "response")

# Putting together the actual weights

data_visit1$weight <- ifelse(data2$attrition == 1, pn_visit1 / pd_visit1, (1- pn_visit1)/(1 - (pd_visit1)))
```

Following this, I rejoin the weights back to the full dataset and then repeat the process for each round of follow up visits. So my question is, does this all look good? I would love any and all feedback on my approach. Thanks so much!

Comment: You might find the [`ipw`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ipw/index.html) package helpful. The [Vignette for the package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v043i13) discusses survival models.

Comment: Also, instead of a for loop, it's better to take advantage of [vectorization](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html): `ifelse(dplyr::lead(data$visit) == 0, 1, 0)`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the general approach. I would think that the right way to handle people dropping out of longitudinal studies is to model it as censored data.